# convert object into an array with the given order

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

```
order = ['mercury', 'venus', 'earth', 'mars', 'jupiter', 'saturn', 'uranus', 'neptune', 'pluto'];

var scrambled = {
  pluto : 'pluto very far',
  mars: 'mars very near',
  saturn: 'saturn dnt care',
  jupiter: 'jupiter',
  uranus : 'uranus',
  earth: 'earth',
  mercury: 'mercury',
  venus: 'venus',
  neptune: 'neptune'
};
```

need to extract the object into an array with the given order,

I am looking for a solution which can solve this is max of 2 to 3 lines.

Comment: *"how to get the array with a given order"* The array already is in the right order, isn't it? You have it already. There is nothing to get :) `order.map(x => scrambled[x])`.

Comment: Is that supposed to be an array of strings?

Answer (score 3):

There is no need of any external library use native JavaScript [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method.

```
// iterate over order array
var res = order.map(function(k) {
  // generate array element based 
  // on the order array element
  return scrambled[k];
});

// with ES6 arrow function

var res = order.map(k => scrambled[k]);
```

```js
order = ['mercury', 'venus', 'earth', 'mars', 'jupiter', 'saturn', 'uranus', 'neptune', 'pluto'];

var scrambled = {
  pluto: 'pluto very far',
  mars: 'mars very near',
  saturn: 'saturn dnt care',
  jupiter: 'jupiter',
  uranus: 'uranus',
  earth: 'earth',
  mercury: 'mercury',
  venus: 'venus',
  neptune: 'neptune'
};

var res = order.map(function(k) {
  return scrambled[k];
});

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use lodash's [`_.at()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.16.0#at):

```js
var order = ['mercury', 'venus', 'earth', 'mars', 'jupiter', 'saturn', 'uranus', 'neptune', 'pluto'];

var scrambled = {
  pluto : 'pluto very far',
  mars: 'mars very near',
  saturn: 'saturn dnt care',
  jupiter: undefined,
  uranus : 'uranus',
  earth: 'earth',
  mercury: 'mercury',
  venus: 'venus',
  neptune: 'neptune'
};

var result = _.at(scrambled, order);

console.log('with undefineds', result);

var result = _.filter(_.at(scrambled, order), _.negate(_.isUndefined)); // filter out all undefined items

console.log('without undefineds', result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.16.1/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: In cases where scrambled has missing fields that might show as undefined in the array.
here is a soln to that 

var res = _.remove(_.at(scrambled, order), function(n){ 
  return !_.isUndefined(n);
});

Comment: I prefer this - `_.filter(_.at(scrambled, order), _.negate(_.isUndefined));`. Added it to answer.

Answer (score 0):

Pure JS this should do it

```js
var order = ['mercury', 'venus', 'earth', 'mars', 'jupiter', 'saturn', 'uranus', 'neptune', 'pluto'],
scrambled = {
  pluto : 'pluto very far',
  mars: 'mars very near',
  saturn: 'saturn dnt care',
  jupiter: 'jupiter',
  uranus : 'uranus',
  earth: 'earth',
  mercury: 'mercury',
  venus: 'venus',
  neptune: 'neptune'
},
   sorted = order.map(k => scrambled[k]);
console.log(sorted);
```